# Formatting double value with specified number of decimals

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to format based on specified number of decimal places.

Eg: value=0.012877
    decimalPlaces=3

```
format-number(value,'how to declare here based on specified decimal places')
```

i know general format: format-number(value,'0.00') but here decimal places are fixed but in my case it would change according to my decimal places, so please any one help me out.

Thanks,
@nag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sequence constructors...

```
<xsl:variable name="decimalPlaces" select="3" />
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(0.012877, substring('0.0000000000000',1,$decimalPlaces+2))"/>
```

...emit...

```
0.013
```

...as a string.

In the value-of instruction, write as many zeros as the maximum range for $decimalPlaces.

Comment: Thank you its working. Is there any other ways to do it other than taking max zeros to formating.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0? or 2.0?

Comment: I'm using 1.0, its ok tell me is there any way to do in 2.0 also.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.0 a more direct approach is

```
round-half-to-even($number, $decimalPlaces)
```

Comment: It's rounding the value or returns me value based on decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple XSLT 1.0 solution that doesn't need a (potentially unlimited) string of zeroes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNum" select="0.012877"/>
 <xsl:param name="pPrec" select="3"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pNum, '.'), '.')"/>

   <xsl:if test="contains($pNum, '.')">
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after($pNum,'.'), 1, $pPrec)"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
0.012
```